# Do Mutexes need initialization in Go?

Tags: go, locking, mutex

I am writing some thread-safe thingy in Go. I try to use Mutexes.

The example I've found [here](https://gobyexample.com/mutexes), seems to use the Mutexes without any initialization:

```
...
// essential part of the referred page
// (it is not my code, I know the pointer is unneeded here,
// it is the code of the referred site in the link - @peterh)

var mutex = &sync.Mutex{}
var readOps uint64 = 0
var writeOps uint64 = 0

for r := 0; r < 100; r++ {
    go func() {
        total := 0
        for {
            key := rand.Intn(5)
            mutex.Lock()
....
```

I am a little bit surprised. Is it real, that they don't need any initialization?

Comment: The non-triviality of the question lies in the fact, that testing concurrent code on a *reliable* way is non-trivial.

Comment: A mutex is a value, and you're initializing that value. From the docs: `the zero value for a Mutex is an unlocked mutex`. What other initialization do you expect to have to do?

Comment: @JimB What if I compile it into C code, and its memory location gets some trash? Is it guaranteed to start from zero after initialization?

Comment: @JimB Yes, it is, as the answer says. Thank you very much!

Comment: "What if I compile it into C code, and its memory location gets some trash" - all bets are off if you're overwriting arbitrary memory locations with arbitrary data. Nothing, mutex or otherwise, can be assumed to work correctly at that point.

Comment: Many says the pointers are unneeded in the example code. This example code of the refered http://gobyexample.com . It is good to know, that their examples aren't always perfect. There is a rule on the SE against the link rotting, that refering an external source, its essential content should be included into the post, this is what I did. This is why I think it shouldn't be fixed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A mutex does not need initialization.

Also that could just be var mutex sync.Mutex, there's no need for a pointer, same for the int values, there's no need to set them to 0, so that example you found could be improved. In all these cases the zero value is fine.

See this bit of effective go:

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#data

> Since the memory returned by new is zeroed, it's helpful to arrange
>   when designing your data structures that the zero value of each type
>   can be used without further initialization. This means a user of the
>   data structure can create one with new and get right to work. For
>   example, the documentation for bytes.Buffer states that "the zero
>   value for Buffer is an empty buffer ready to use." Similarly,
>   sync.Mutex does not have an explicit constructor or Init method.
>   Instead, the zero value for a sync.Mutex is defined to be an unlocked
>   mutex.

Comment: Wow, this key information missed I until now, that newly allocated variables start with zeroed out memory :-) Thanks.

Comment: "there's no need for a pointer" is misleading - if it's ever passed to a function (e.g. when starting a goroutine) *you absolutely must use a pointer or it will not work*.

Comment: @Adrian can you point me to a ref for that? I usually bundle mutexes with the data they control, the containing struct is usually a pointer but not the mutex itself.

Comment: Which is fine, because you're modifying one copy of the mutex (the one stored in the struct). But if you pass the mutex itself, or pass a struct containing a mutex (not a pointer to the struct) you'll create a copy. Per the [`sync`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/) package docs: "Values containing the types defined in this package should not be copied."

Comment: In the example given though I think the mutex doesn't need to be a pointer? i.e. https://play.golang.org/p/sN0_MFdCKP

Comment: @KennyGrant that example works because it is using the same `Mutex` variable in the closure. If you pass it to a function, you have to pass a pointer. If you don't, you will be passing the struct __value__ instead of a pointer, and Go is pass by value so it would be a copy.

Comment: When I searched for examples of Mutex use online everyone seemed to be using a pointer, and I found no good reason to do so and didn't use one.  Nice to know that I was right about that.  Good point Adrian about needing a pointer to pass it to a function because you do not want to copy the mutex object!!  But I was just referring to it as a global and so were the examples I saw.

Comment: In the specific example, no pointer is required. If the mutex is embedded in a struct, no pointer is required, so I think using pointers for mutexes should only be done if/when they are being passed as a param into a function.